# django template display item value or empty string

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My code in template is like this:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.somefield }}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to display the item value if the item.somefield is not None, or display an empty string. I don't want to use the {% if item.somefield %} statement, I want something like {{ item.somefield or '' }}(I tried this but it doesn't work)

Answer (score 324, accepted):

You want the `default_if_none` template filter, ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none)).

`default_if_none` will display the given string if the variable is 'None'.

`default` will display the string if the variable evaluates to False, ie empty strings, empty lists etc

```
{{ item.somefield|default_if_none:"" }}
{{ item.somefield|default:"" }}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
{{ item.somefield|default_if_none:"" }}
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation to your answer, rather than just code. This helps the person who asked the question to better understand your answer.